# Manipulate gem options from the ruby command line

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is there a way to tell rubygems to only look for gems locally on the disk from the ruby interpreter (irb or sketchup ruby console)?

example: Gem.install 'savon','=2.1.1','--local'

Comment: You have those gems already installed?

Comment: Yes I have them installed currently from the internet but would like to test on another pc which will have no internet access, just local network access for its needs (database, webservice access).

Comment: Do you really have to solve this via `irb` restrictions, or can you use bundler?  If you can use bundler instead, `bundle package` ([docs](http://bundler.io/v1.10/bundle_package.html)) will cache the installed gem bundle in `./vendor/cache`.  Then if you do `bundle install --local`, you will avoid the rubygems.org lookup. More reading: [1](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/), [2](http://words.steveklabnik.com/how-to-not-rely-on-rubygemsorg-for-deployment)

Comment: if bundler can be manipulated thru the irb or sketchup console (which is kind of the same thing) then it could be used, but I would prefer if an additional gem like bundler not be used.

Comment: I mean...if you have them already installed, and they can be found in your `$LOAD_PATH`, you can just then do `require 'gem'` and that's it. You don't  need rubygems as you won't install anything else

Comment: I have them installed in a specific pc (in both ruby 2.0 and Sketchup 2014 which uses the same ruby version), but I also need them to be able to be installed on any pc at school which may or may not have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the way to do that is to download the .gem file to your computer and then run:

```
gem install savon-*.gem
```

Comment: sorry if I didnt say clearly, I need to do it from inside the ruby interpreter not commandline.